# Implementation of Multiprocessing in images

Tags: python, image-processing, multiprocessing, nifti

I am running a fisher exact test on each voxel of two images of size (240,240,155). I only have basic knowledge in multiprocessing and am unsure on how to apply it to my case.

This is the code I am trying to run:

```
result_array = np.zeros_like(imgRHUH, dtype=float)

for (x_RHUH,y_RHUH,z_RHUH), valueRHUH in np.ndenumerate(imgRHUH):
    for (x_BTP,y_BTP,z_BTP), valueBTP in np.ndenumerate(imgBTP):
        a = int(valueRHUH)
        b = int(valueBTP)
        c = 39 - a
        d = 20 - b
        n = 2
         
        p = (math.factorial(a + b)*math.factorial(c + d)*math.factorial(a + c)*math.factorial(b + d)) / (math.factorial(a)*math.factorial(b)*math.factorial(c)*math.factorial(d)*math.factorial(n))

        result_array[x_RHUH, y_RHUH, z_RHUH] = p
```

I have tried splitting the first image into chunks like this

```
chunks = []
for chunk in np.array_split(list(np.ndenumerate(imgRHUH)), multiprocessing.cpu_count()):
   chunks.append((chunk, imgRHUH, imgBTP, result_array))
```

, but this didn't seem to improve performance by much. Furthermore I am afraid that even if this end up completing it might merge the image back together in the wrong way ?

Comment: The inner loop computes stuff and writes it to the same output location over and over again. So only the last iteration of that loop is meaningful. I’m sure this is not what you intended. Doing this pointless work faster is not a solution.

Comment: You're completely right. That's a major blunder on my part. Thank you for pointing that out!